# Flutter: Widget not reloading with `provider` package when using `notifyListeners`

Tags: flutter, dart, mvvm, state, flutter-provider

I'm building a chat app using Flutter with the MVVM pattern and the `provider` package. Right now, I'm trying to implement the screen to show the list of chats a user has.

Here is my ViewModel class:

```dart
class ConversationsViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final MatchesService chatService = MatchesService();

  final String userId;

  final List<ChatCell> chatCells = [];

  ConversationsViewModel({required this.userId}) {
    loadChats();
  }

  void loadChats() async {
    final chats = await chatService.getChats(userId: userId);

    for (final chat in chats) {
      final messages = await chatService.getMessages(
        userId: userId,
        chatId: chat.chatId,
        limit: 1,
      );

      final cell = ChatCell(chat: chat, message: messages.first);
      chatCells.add(cell);

      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my widget:

```dart
class Conversations extends StatefulWidget {
  const Conversations({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ConversationsState createState() => _ConversationsState();
}

class _ConversationsState extends State<Conversations> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Selector<ConversationsViewModel, List<ChatCell>>(
          selector: (context, vm) => vm.chatCells,
          builder: (context, chatCells, _) {
            return ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: chatCells.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                  Text(chatCells[index].message.message.body),
            );
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

However, for some reason, the widget never reloads even when `notifyListeners` is called.

I'm not too sure what's wrong, since afaik I am following all the patterns and usage that the `provider` package dictates.

I also tried invoking `loadChats` in `initState` but realized that was even more wrong than doing so in the VM's constructor.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you wrap your MaterialApp with ChangeNotifierProvider?
Example:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) => ConversationsViewModel(),
    child: MaterialApp()
)
```

Comment: Yes, I have done that

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you are not defining your provider, so you can't access its data. Under your build method you should add something like this:

```
final conversationsProvider = Provider.of<ConversationsViewModel>(context);
```

And then you can use it by doing:

```
conversationsProvider.chatCells;
```